# How to show a list in JFrame/JPanel and refresh it after button click?

Tags: java, arraylist, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

I don't have an idea how to show my list of objects (regardless of parameters) one by one in JFrame. I would like to use a loop for doing it. I want to show first 10 elements and next 10 elements after button click etc. Any ideas?

Comment: ActionListener and revalidate()...

Answer (score 0):

i think it wouldn't work for me... i've added a list in JList to a JPanel and after button click it refreshes at all but when i click on actually showed JList elements their are coming back to the first ones - to the beginning... (the repaint() command is commented because with it i don't see any changes of my JList). these same effect i have when remove() and revalidate() commands are also commented... so i don't know where the problem is...

```
public Window()
{
    setTitle("Window");
    setSize(600,600);
    setResizable(false);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);

    JList<?> list = new JList<Object>(tmp_list.toArray());
    listPanel = new JPanel();
    listPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    listPanel.add(new JScrollPane(list));
    add(listPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    nextButton = new JButton("Next");
    buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonsPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    buttonsPanel.add(nextButton);
    add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    nextButton.addActionListener(this);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{   
    Object source = e.getSource();

    if(source == nextButton)
    {
        if(current_page < last_page)
        {
            current_page++;
            refreshListPanel();
        }
    }
}

private void refreshListPanel()
{
    listPanel.removeAll();
    tmp_list = showCurrentPage(N, cars1);
    JList<?> list = new JList<Object>(tmp_list.toArray());
    listPanel.add(new JScrollPane(list));
    listPanel.revalidate();
    listPanel.repaint();
}

private List<Car> showCurrentPage(int n, List<Car> main_list)
{
    List<Car> list = new ArrayList<Car>();
    int counter = n*(current_page);
    int size;
    if(current_page == last_page && C%N != 0)
        size = main_list.size()%n;
    else
        size = n;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        list.add(main_list.get(counter + i));
    }
    return list;
}
```